# CSS stopped loading after updating

Tags: 8, updating

For some reason, my Drupal 8 page it's just showing plain text after performing an update (8.1.8). I unchecked the *Aggregate CSS and JavaScript files* option, and cleaned the cache, but it didn't work. Everything was working fine, until I did the update.

How can I fix this?

Update:

Report/status Report shows this

> ```
> Protection disabled
> The file sites/default/settings.php is not protected from modifications and poses a security risk. You must change the file's permissions to be non-writable.
> The file sites/default/settings.local.php is not protected from modifications and poses a security risk. You must change the file's permissions to be non-writable.
> ```

Comment: what steps did you do to perform the update?

Comment: @NoSssweat same steps that I did to update from preview versions by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlLq05X5xKw

Comment: you ran update.php right?

Comment: have you tried switching themes? switch to a default core theme, like bartik to see what happens.

Comment: Yes, I did run update.php but I got an error "
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."  And yes, I did switch to other themes and it didn't work =/

Comment: Did you backup your site before upgrading, like you're suppose to?

Comment: =( nooo...I did like 5 updates before, so I was feeling confident with this one =/

Comment: check your log (/admin/reports/dblog) and see if there are more errors there.

Comment: @NoSssweat I checked the Recent log messages, i didn't see anything new there.  Then I checked the Status Report...please, check my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43555/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-ariel-maduro).